# How can I prevent wasps from nesting in my eaves?

Tags: pest-control

Every season paper and / or mud wasps like to build nests in my eaves. I have no compunction with spraying them with raid when I see them but I'd like to prevent the nesting from the start if I can.

I don't mind using chemicals.

I don't mind wasps on the property in general but I specifically don't want them under these particular eaves.

Comment: A quick shot with a garden hose would send them packing without making a poison packet for some predator or scavenger.

Comment: I'm looking for a long lasting solution to this as well.  I welcome the use of chemicals, only if they are severe enough to not wash away every time it rains.  I'm also interested in measures that require no repeated applications.  Spraying with a garden hose is unacceptable for me, because it is in no way a permanent solution.

Answer (score 3):

Wasps [do not like strong mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentha#Insecticides) fragrance. You could apply mint essence/oils to the problem areas, though I'm not sure if you'll get a whole season of protection from a single application, so you may need to reapply every few weeks. For a more permanent solution you can plant mint, citronella, or other insect repelling plants. Just be aware that practically all mint varieties spread aggressively and are nearly impossible to completely eradicate if you change your mind later. Planting in pots may be preferable.

Using [decoy nests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000W93LUU) appears to come with mixed reports of success. These are a fairly inexpensive way to address the problem, that you can set and forget. Judging from the review sentiment, it appears to be important that you get your decoys up *before* the wasps show up in spring. If you're too late they'll ignore the decoy or worse, they'll use it as a foundation for their own nest.

Comment: I feel like I would have to reapply the oils every few days. Do you have any context for reapplication requirements?

Comment: [This source](https://plantcaretoday.com/natural-ways-get-rid-wasps.html) suggests a solution of oils and vodka, applied daily for one week and then weekly thereafter. I'm sure that would be very effective, but it sounds like too much work (and money - essential oils can be pretty pricey) for me, I would rather install the plants themselves for a longer term solution. I haven't tried oil deterrents in my own yard (I keep honeybees, so I don't generally treat for any insects other than ants (borax solution) if they are getting inside the house), luckily my wasp population is not above average.